Shakuni's illusions
In Drona Parva (SECTION XXVIII of Ganguly's translation), it is stated as below:

Sakuni also, conversant with a hundred different kinds of illusions, seeing his brothers slain, created illusions for confounding the two Krishnas.

The chapter further explains how Arjuna dispelled those illusions created by Shakuni.
How (or, from whom) did Shakuni learnt these illusions?
